# Accessing TEAMCITY from a remote machine

Tags: teamcity

I am having trouble browsing to my team city(JetBrains) from a remote machine. I have followed the install directions and the install went smoothly. I can browse the to application locally on the server, no problem at all.  I changed the default server url in the config file to be http://my servername . I can browse to http://my server name and the application shows up no problem locally.  The application is alos installed on the default 80 port of the server with no other web server installed.

If I browse to http://my servername  from my laptop on the same domian nothing happens.  When I run diagnostics it seems to pick up the webserve but it fails to respond.

As a test I uninstalled the app and installed IIS to see if I could browse to the default IIS page remotely. This worked no problems at all. I uninstalled IIS, ensured nothing was hogging port 80 on the server. Reinstalled the applicaiton, configured it exactly the same, still nothing. The application works fine locally, but I get nothing remotely.

I was just wondering if anybody knows anything else I can try?  or is there a setting in tomcat I need to tweak?

Comment: If you want a second pair of eyes looking at your problem, let me know, I can connect through CrossLoop (VNC-type application) and try to help you. But the firewall answer is the first I'd check as well, so not sure I could do/suggest anything.

Answer (score 12):

I just updated TeamCity from 7.0 to 7.1, and now I have the exact same issue.

However, what turned out to be the cause had nothing to do w/ the TeamCity upgrade.  It turns out our system administrators had setup a policy update to block all incoming connections other than port 80.  When I started my upgrade, I noticed the server wanted to do some system updates.  So I let that go first.

I suspect that had I tried to access the TeamCity server *after* the system update, I'd have realized I could no longer access the website remotely.

But since I only noticed it after the TeamCity update, I assumed it to be the culprit and wasted a bunch of time on that red herring.

The solution for me was to

1. Open Windows Firewall on the server
2. Click on the root level option in the left-hand pane
3. Make sure under each of the profile sections, that inbound connections are allowed.

(#3) was my problem.

Hope this helps someone else out in the future...

Comment: interestingly turning the firewall of didnt work but this did, after getting it working like this I added a firewall rule which has solved the problem in a more secure fashion.
Cheers

Comment: Windows Firewall was also an issue for me, but I just created an Incoming rule for port 80, since our Group Policy seems to have locked down the ability to accept all incoming connections.

Comment: Ran into similar firewall issue on linux.

Answer (score 7):

Verify that the server is running on port which is not blocked by the firewall. [Change the port](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD5/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-ChangingServerPort) if necessary.

Tomcat also supports binding to specific IP addresses, in case your machine has multiple IPs, you can configure which one to use in server.xml, like:

```
<Connector port="80" address="10.10.10.10" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Where 10.10.10.10 is the IP of the server which can be accessed from the remote machine.

[Check the server logs](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD5/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-TroubleshootingTeamCityInstallationIssues) to ensure that it's started on the correct IP/port and is accepting connections.

Comment: Thanks for this. However I had tried all these prior to posting. Have double checked and all is ok. 
The firewall lts traffic through as an IIS test page, I Have added more ports to the firewall rules but still nothing

Comment: Try another browser, could be adblock plug-in, content filter proxy or something else on your remote machine that prevents TeamCity page from loading properly. Also from your description it's not clear what's the server URL, it just says http://. Try using IP address instead.

Comment: It is a really wierd problem.  Like I say If install and setup an IIS set, I can navigate to it no problem from any of the machines in my office.  If I unistall IIS and set up the team city on the machine , the website runs fine on the machine, but externally nothing.

Comment: Does it work if you run it on different port and access the server by IP address? Try the clean server installation with all the default configuration (rename ~/.BuildServer directory).

Comment: Hey, just taking a swing at it I noticed that you can get it to bind to all addresses (seems like this is not the default) if you use this setting in the

address="*"
8)

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same issue when evaluating TeamCity v10.0.

I solved it by changing the 'Server URL' value with the name of my computer that can be used from remote computer.

As they say, "make sure the server is accessible by the URL specified".

To reach this setting:
- Login to TeamCity interface then
- Click on the 'Administration' link
[image]

This is well explained in the TeamCity support page:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Server+URL

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that TeamCity's default server.xml has localhost as the host name.  You need to add an alias for it answer that name as well, as described here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/config/host.html#Host%20Name%20Aliases

Ryan