# Accessing TeamCity server works from Firefox but not from IE

Tags: teamcity

I've got TeamCity running on a virtual machine.

From my host, I can access the server with Firefox using the IP, but not with IE.

I could just leave it at that, but apparently getting IE to work is also the key to getting the Windows Tray notified and VS add-in working too.

Any ideas, or troubleshooting steps I could look into?

(I've seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931165/accessing-teamcity-from-a-remote-machine), but it doesn't seem to apply/help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I *think* I've worked out what this is, either that or it's just a coincidence:

In the TCP/IP settings of the virtual machine, I hadn't set the Default Gateway.

Apparently, that nailed it.